# Subtracting two columns of type timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgresql

I'm converting some column types from `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Some functions that already exists in the system calculates the difference between two timestamps by simply doing something like: timestamp1 - timestamp2.

I'm wondering if this approach is correct when dealing with timezones.
The solution I'm thinking of is the following:

```
timestamp1 at time zone 'America/Sao_Paulo' - timestamp2 at time zone 'America/Sao_Paulo'
```

But the question is: this approach handles DST changes correctly? It's safe to subtract timestamps with time zone this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not safe. Consider this example:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPTZ '2018-02-18 02:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo'
     - TIMESTAMPTZ '2018-02-18 01:00:00+00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Sao_Paulo';

 ?column? 
----------
 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

That is because these different absolute timestamps look the same in that time zone. Date arithmetic with `timestamp without time zone` just isn't correct, because the difference depends on the time zone.

To find the elapsed time between two `timestamp with time zone` values, simply subtract them:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPTZ '2018-02-18 02:00:00+00'
     - TIMESTAMPTZ '2018-02-18 01:00:00+00';

 ?column? 
----------
 01:00:00
(1 row)
```

That result is always correct, because absolute time is used.

Comment: But if I simply subtract them, how Postgres would know how long 1 day is? Because of DST changes 1 day may have 23 hours. This simply subtraction will cover that case? I don't understand how this could work.

Comment: If you store `timestamp with time zone`, DST is trrelevant, because internally everything is done in UTC. Try `SET timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';` and then `SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-02-19 00:00:00'::timestamptz - TIMESTAMP '2018-02-17 00:00:00'::timestamptz;`. And that's the correct result, because these two days took 49 hours.

Comment: You are right! That works perfectly, thanks. But I still don't know how applying the timezone info does not work and when using UTC it takes into account days that have different hours.

Comment: I tried to explain it in my answer. When you cast to `timestamp with time zone`, the current setting of `timezone` is used to compute what that timestamp means in absolute time.

Comment: I'm thinking in this solution again. So when we subtract a TIMESTAMPTZ it uses the current session timezone to compute DST changes, is that right? This is basically the point of all my question, per your answer I still don't know how this subtraction will use 'America/Sao_Paulo' to compute the DST or any another tz of my choice (the costumer's tz, in that case).

Comment: If you subtract two `timestamp with time zone` values, your session time zone does not come into play at all. Both values are stored in microseconds since `2000-01-01 00:00:00`, and PostgreSQL more or less just subtracts the values.